# Why is //element selecting too many elements in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working on a project where I need to be able to transform an XML document, and need to be able to identify the `Name` of the `Opportunity`, but the xpath expression `//Name` returns the `Name` of the `Owner` and the `Name` of the `Opportunity`.

[Demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9dd234d084c93f92ac59d11807ab15ee)

Example XML:

```
  <root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <Opportunity>
      <Owner>
        <Name>Christian Bale</Name>
      </Owner>
      <Name>Opportunity Name</Name>
    </Opportunity>
  </root>
```

I can't seem to find a predicate that will only return the name of the opportunity.  Because both are the last `Name` element at their level, `//Name[last()]` and `//Name[1]` still returns both.

Is it possible to write an XPath expression that only returns the `Name` of the `Opportunity` and not the name of the `Opportunity` `Owner`?  Or is it possible to eliminate one of the matching notes after it has been selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that `//` selects descendants (or self), so it skips heritage by design.  To specify heritage, use `/`, which selects along the child axis by default:

```
/root/Opportunity/Name
```

is then separately selectable from

```
/root/Opportunity/Owner/Name
```

as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`//Opportunity/Name/text()`